# How to get the input of a EditText without clicking a button in a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

**Summary**

I have a CardView in a RecycleView with a EditText element and I would like to get the user input without needing him to click a button, or press enter, and compare it with a predefined string.

I have tried many tutorials, even answers in stackOverflow, but it still don't seem to work. My idea was to implement the TextWatcher in my Adapter class to get the input data. Below is my attempt so far (if I take away all the related EditText content, the code runs fine). Bellow is my attempt:

**MyAdapter code**

```
public class MyAdapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter2.MyViewHolder>{
private Context mContext;
private List<CardAudioGrid> mList;
private OnItemClickListener mListener;

private int nowPlaying = -1;

private String ans;

public interface OnItemClickListener{
    void onPlayClick (int position);
}


public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
    mListener = listener;
}

public MyAdapter2(Context mContext, List<CardAudioGrid> mList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mList = mList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.audiocard, viewGroup, false);
    //when I try to run the code, it shows the error: ...MyAdapter2.MyViewHolder is not an enclosing class
    return new MyViewHolder(view, mListener, new MyViewHolder.MyCustomEditTextListener());
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.audioCardBackground.setImageResource(mList.get(position).getCardBackground());
...
    holder.myCustomEditTextListener.updatePosition(holder.getLayoutPosition());
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mList.size();
}
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    ImageView mediaPlayer, audioCardBackground;
    EditText toonName;
    MyCustomEditTextListener myCustomEditTextListener;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener, MyCustomEditTextListener myCustomEditTextListener) {
        super(itemView);

        itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardbackgroundId);
        ...

        this.myCustomEditTextListener = myCustomEditTextListener;

        mediaPlayer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(listener!=null){
                    int position = getLayoutPosition();
                    nowPlaying = position;
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        listener.onPlayClick(position);
                        notifyDataSetChanged(); //restarts the views
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //I want the EditText to watch what the user is typing. Every change should be compared
    //to the names string given from when adding mList items
    private class MyCustomEditTextListener implements TextWatcher{
        private int position;
        public void updatePosition(int position) {
            this.position = position;
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            ans = s.toString().toLowerCase();
            if (ans == mList.get(position).getName()){
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    }

}
}
```

The error of my attempt is commented in the code above. How should I implement this idea?

I am currently learning how to manage the android properly, so I would really appreciate if you explain the steps' solutions.

Comment: so you want all editetext data which are available in recyclerview list?

Comment: Yes, the idea is basically to watch every EditText in the recyclerView and every time one is modified, I would get this input and compare with a string associated to that specific EditText.

Comment: okay,
i post answer for getting all recycerlview data on button click

Answer (score 0):

Apply this:

```
toonName.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    toonName.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
                    toonName.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
                } else {
                    toonName.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
                }
            });
```

Comment: But I don't want to get the input after changing the focus from an editText to another item, I want it to get the string after every input's modification in the EditText

Answer (score 0):

inside `onTextChanged()`

Use

```
ans = s.toString().toLowerCase();
            if (ans.equals(mList.get(position).getName())){
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
```

Comment: Why .equals instead of == ?

Comment: while i can't guarantee you the code will be the ultimate solution to the issue you raised, do note that comparing two string with == is not a reliable thing to do.
So for string comparison user .equals();
And one of the reasons is that == checks for reference value, and not always the actual string.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know this .equals() task, thanks! But would you know how to solve the issue or could you point some material for me to understand better this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the code for getting all recyerview list item data on button click**

```
 integerArrayList= my array of data which i have passed to adapter

            ArrayList<FormDataItems> formDataItemsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();      
                for (int i = 0; i < integerArrayList.size(); i++) {
                    View view = rvForm.getChildAt(i);
                    EditText etName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etName);
                    EditText etMobile = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etMobile);
                    RadioGroup rgGender = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.rbGender);


                    String strName = etName.getText().toString();
                    String strNumber = etMobile.getText().toString();

                    //add in to array for further use
                    FormDataItems formDataItems = new FormDataItems(strName, gender, strNumber);
                    formDataItemsArrayList.add(formDataItems);

                }
```

write this code on button click  and elements id is same as recyclerview cell/item.xml